# How to show and hide legends in google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Could anyone let me know which is the best method to show/hide line legends (If using a checkbox for changing the visibility).

I should be having maximum 7 legends in line chart.

**My code is below:**

```
function DrawGraph(chartsdata, title, charttype) {

    //debugger;
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(DrawChart);

    function DrawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', '');
        data.addColumn('number', '');

        try {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartsdata);
        }
        catch (e) {
            //debugger;
            //document.writeln(e);
        }

        var optionsBar = {
            title: title,
            isStacked: true,
            hAxis: {
                type: "datetime",
                showTextEvery: 1,
                ticks: [2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023]
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                textStyle: { fontSize: 12 }
            }
        };

        var optionsLine = {
            title: title,
            //width: 500,
            seriesType: 'line',
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                textStyle: { fontSize: 11 }
            }
        };

        if (charttype == "line") {
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
            chart.draw(data, optionsLine);
        }
        else {
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
            chart.draw(data, optionsBar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43004583/5090771) for complete example of show / hide lines with checkboxes _and_ keep the line colors consistent for each series...

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the legend by using `none`/`bottom` as the position:

```
legend: {position: 'none'} //to hide
```

Comment: How can I select specific legend in run time and hide?

Comment: I mean to hide the lines on check box checks?