# Setting color in Stepped Area Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am working on the following google chart that has buttons to hide the different fields. Problem is that when a field is hidden, the remaining columns change color. Is there a way to fix the color for each field? I saw some other answers to this, but the chart was created in a different way than I am doing.

Also, if there is a way to use check boxes instead of the buttons so I can toggle the fields on and off that would be great.

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Chart Date', 'LNW1', 'TNW1', 'LNW2', 'TNW2'],
     ['Jul-13', 12, 20, 0, 10,],
     ['Aug-13', 100, 200, 50, 10,],
     ['Sep-13', 120, 200, 0, 20,],
     ['Oct-13', 1200, 2000, 50, 50,],       
     ['Nov-13', 1200, 200, 200, 100,],      
     ['Dec-13', 1200, 20, 0, 0,]
     ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Report TNW & LNW',
      vAxis: {title: 'none'},
      isStacked: false
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

    var HideLNW1 = document.getElementById("HideLNW1");
    HideLNW1.onclick = function()
    {
    view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.hideColumns([1]); 
    chart.draw(view, options);
    }

    var HideTNW1 = document.getElementById("HideTNW1");
    HideTNW1.onclick = function()
    {
    view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.hideColumns([2]); 
    chart.draw(view, options);
    }

    var HideLNW2 = document.getElementById("HideLNW2");
    HideLNW2.onclick = function()
    {
    view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.hideColumns([3]); 
    chart.draw(view, options);
    }

    var HideTNW2 = document.getElementById("HideTNW2");
    HideTNW2.onclick = function()
    {
    view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.hideColumns([4]); 
    chart.draw(view, options);
    }


  }
</script>
</head>
<button type="button" id="HideLNW1"  >Hide LNW1</button>
<button type="button" id="HideTNW1"  >Hide TNW1</button>
<button type="button" id="HideLNW2"  >Hide LNW2</button>
<button type="button" id="HideTNW2"  >Hide TNW2</button>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004583/5090771)...