# google charts show/hide JSON line chart data via checkbox selections based on PHP javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, checkbox, charts

> Blockquote

I did not see any examples for this combination, and i am not able to get my code to fully functional. The check boxes seems to have no effect but the table/ chat does still draw. So the javascript is not targeting the Jason data correctly. If anyone can point me in the right direction or help out as other people may come across this same scenario.

```
enter code here <?php

$dbname = 'blah';
$username = 'blahblah';
$password = 'blahblahblah';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username,$password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM blah Where blahblah = 'blahblahblah' ");
  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'blah0', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'blah1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah2', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah3', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah4', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah5', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah6', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah7', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah8', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'blah9', 'type' => 'number')

);

    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['blah0']);           
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah1']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah2']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah3']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah4']);
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah5']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah6']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah7']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah8']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['blah9']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>


end code
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

      var options =  {
        chart: {
          title: '',
          subtitle: ''
        }
           
      };
   
      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
     chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
   
   $('#label').find(':checkbox').change(function () {
        var cols = [0];
        var colors = [];   
        $('#label').find(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            console.log(this);
            var value = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
            cols.push(value);
            colors.push(seriesColors[value - 1]);
            console.log(value, 'colors: ', colors);
        });
    view.setColumns(cols);
        
        chart.draw(view, {
            strictFirstColumnType: true,
            colors: colors
        }); 
     });
    
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        if (selection.length > 0) {
            alert('selected label: ' + selection[0].column);
        } 
     });
    }
    
    </script>
```

```html
 </head>
 <div>
 <center>
  <body>
    <ul id="label" >
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="1" checked="false" /> Value1</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="2" checked="true" /> V2</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="3" checked="true" /> V3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="4" checked="true" /> V4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="5" checked="true" /> V5</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="6" checked="true" /> V6</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="7" checked="true" /> V7</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="8" checked="true" /> V8</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="label" value="9" checked="true" /> V9</li>
    </ul>
   </center>
 <p></p>  
  </div>
    <div id="linechart_material"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004583/5090771)...

Comment: yeah i have seen something like that, but it is applied to static data and not addressing a SQL-json output.