# How can I maintain line (series) colours in Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a [Line Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) from Google Charts library set up so that lines (series) can be toggled on and off.

I also fix the values of the line colours in the chart options:

```
series: {
    0: { color: '#082882' },
    1: { color: '#049587' },
    ...
}
```

When I toggle off one of the series, the colours of the lines still change! For example if I switch off series-0 then series-1 colour becomes #082882 when it should remain as #049587.

Is there a way to fix the values that I have missed? Or will I need to dynamically update the series' colours myself?

Comment: you'll have to change the options as the series are toggled on & off, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004583/5090771)...