# How to filter a Google Visualization Chart by row headers (categories) instead of first column

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a google line chart that shows the months on the x axis and the amounts on the y axis.

I am trying to create a category filter that will filter the chart based on the column categories (in my example it's:

`column1, column2, column3, column4, column5`

All my attempts at creating a category filter result in the first column being the filter (months) instead of the categories being the filters.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['line','controls','corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var jsonData = [{"month":"February","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"March","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"April","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"May","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"June","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"July","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"August","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"September","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"October","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"November","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"December","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"Total","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{}];

  // create blank data table
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  // parse json
  jsonData.forEach(function (jsonRow, indexRow) {
    // add columns
    if (indexRow === 0) {
      for (var column in jsonRow) {
        if (column === 'month') {
          data.addColumn('string', column);
        } else {
          data.addColumn('number', column);
        }
      }
    }

    // add row
    var dataRow = [];
    for (var column in jsonRow) {
      if (column === 'month') {
        dataRow.push(jsonRow[column]);
      } else {
        // convert string to number
        dataRow.push(parseFloat(jsonRow[column]));
      }
    }
    if (dataRow.length > 0) {
      data.addRow(dataRow);
    }
  });

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard'));
var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
            containerId: 'line_top_x_control',
            options: {
                filterColumnIndex: 0,
            }
        });

  var chart  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Line',
        'containerId': 'line_top_x',
        'options': {
          'width': 900,
          'height': 200,
        }
      });
 // var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
  
  dashboard.bind(categoryPicker, chart);
  dashboard.draw(data);
  //chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
<div id="line_top_x_control"></div>
<div id="line_top_x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: for clarification, do you want to be able to select which columns appear in the chart? or do you want to filter on the values of the columns? for the latter, change `filterColumnIndex`. current value = 0, which is the month column. 1 would = column1, 2 = column2, etc...

Comment: @WhiteHat The first. I need to select which columns appear in the chart. The selections in the drop-down should be column1 through column5.

Comment: the category filter will not add the column names out of the box. you would have to manually load the filter. which means you won't be able to bind to the chart. does it have to be a category filter, or would something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004583/5090771) work?

Comment: I think that would work. I'm currently attempting to do that but I'm getting "Invalid column index NaN". https://jsfiddle.net/3e8cL576/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you received was from the value of the checkboxes.
the value needs to be the index of the column --> `1`
not the name of the column --> `column1`

also, you'll want to set the colors manually,
because when you hide a series,
the rest of the series will change colors.

also, you'll want to use either `vAxis.ticks` or `vAxis.viewWindow`,
to lock the y-axis in place.
otherwise, when you hide a series,
the y-axis will rescale and the series will move.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['line','controls','corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var jsonData = [{"month":"February","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"March","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"April","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"May","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"June","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"July","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"August","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"September","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"October","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"November","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"December","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{"month":"Total","column1":"1","column2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5"},{}];

  // create blank data table
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  // parse json
  jsonData.forEach(function (jsonRow, indexRow) {
    // add columns
    if (indexRow === 0) {
      for (var column in jsonRow) {
        if (column === 'month') {
          data.addColumn('string', column);
        } else {
          data.addColumn('number', column);
        }
      }
    }

    // add row
    var dataRow = [];
    for (var column in jsonRow) {
      if (column === 'month') {
        dataRow.push(jsonRow[column]);
      } else {
        // convert string to number
        dataRow.push(parseFloat(jsonRow[column]));
      }
    }
    if (dataRow.length > 0) {
      data.addRow(dataRow);
    }
  });

  var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];
  colors.forEach(function (color, index) {
    data.setColumnProperty(index + 1, 'color', color);
  });

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      top: 12,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 72,
      left: 72
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    colors: colors,
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      title: 'Amount'
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '90%'
    },
    height: 400
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));

  $('.series-chk').on('change', drawChart);
  $(window).resize(drawChart);
  drawChart();

  function drawChart() {
    var chartColors = [];
    var chartColumns = [0];
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    $.each($('.series-chk'), function (index, checkbox) {
      var seriesColumn = parseInt(checkbox.value);
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        chartColumns.push(seriesColumn);
        chartColors.push(data.getColumnProperty(seriesColumn, 'color'));
      }
    });

    view.setColumns(chartColumns);
    options.colors = chartColors;
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<input class="series-chk" id="chk-0" type="checkbox" value="1" checked /><label for="chk-0">Column 1</label>
<input class="series-chk" id="chk-1" type="checkbox" value="2" checked /><label for="chk-1">Column 2</label>
<input class="series-chk" id="chk-2" type="checkbox" value="3" checked /><label for="chk-2">Column 3</label>
<input class="series-chk" id="chk-3" type="checkbox" value="4" checked /><label for="chk-3">Column 4</label>
<input class="series-chk" id="chk-4" type="checkbox" value="5" checked /><label for="chk-4">Column 5</label>
<div id="line_top_x"></div>
```