# How can google chart table colum filter be a dropdown with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

Is there a way to filter google charts table columns (show/hide columns) in dropdown with checkboxes? With current filtering you have to add one by one column and they are being added on the side or bottom from where you can remove them.

It is bad user experience, and would like to allow user while dropdown is open to filter (show/hide) every column user wants or just one depending on the needs.

HTML

```
<div id="colFilter_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

JS

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Foo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Bar');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Baz');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cad');
    data.addRows([
        ['2005',  45, 60, 89, 100],
        ['2006',  155, 50, 79, 24],
        ['2007',  35, 31, 140, 53],
        ['2008',  105, 23, 43, 82],
        ['2009',  120, 56, 21, 67],
        ['2010',  65, 19, 34, 134],
        ['2011',  80, 23, 130, 40],
        ['2012',  70, 140, 83, 90]
    ]);

    var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
    var initState= {selectedValues: []};
    // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
    }
    initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(4));
    
    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Table',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            title: 'Foobar',
            width: 600,
            height: 400
        }
    });
    
    var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'colFilter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label: 'Columns',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        },
        state: initState
    });
    
    function setChartView () {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
            row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
            view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        }
        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });
        chart.setView(view);
        chart.draw();
    }
    google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);
    
    setChartView();
    columnFilter.draw();
}
```

You can also check JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/WaUu2/157/)

Comment: there are a number of ways, you found one example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004583/5090771) is another. build your own drop-down and use similar code...

Comment: i was trying with Jquery.sumoselect to create dropdown, but i just don't know api enough to write the rest of the logic, show / hide columns. i saw this example and many other you provided (since i saw you answer most of google charts problems) but still after few days i cannot make it work.

Comment: @WhiteHat if you ever get a chace to show me some sample on this I would really appreciate it. Thanks a lot in advance.